# Can I get dn(Distinguish Name) of a group from Common name of a group

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am facing an issue I have to create group in Hierarchical manner.
But as and input I am getting only the parent cn(common name).Can I create a child group only from Parents' common name.
For Example if I have main group A
Children Groups AA,AB
AAA,AAB are children of AA
ABA,ABB are children of AB

so when I will create AAA group I will only parent common name (i.e. AA) 
but to create group I will need cn=AAA,cn=AA,cn=A 
How can I search my parent group's dn?

I am using groupOfNames .

Comment: Same way you search for any other DN, but it will only work if the parent CN is unique. What's the reason for the existence of this problem?

Comment: parent CN is unique but I am not getting the whole hierarchy as an input only the child group (to be created) and parent group.So to create a hierarchy what can I do?